# Google and Facebook Login causing error with JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, facebook-login, google-signin

I am facing this weird issue where

```
function signup(data, success, error) {
    var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(payload);
}
```

gives error at JSON.stringify which goes like:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://xxxx:1111"
>   from accessing a frame with origin "https://accounts.google.com".  The
>   frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being
>   accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

Please help if anyone knows a solution

PS: I am not making any request to a server. I have included google and fb's login SDKs, which are creating the iframes. I am simply using console.log, with JSON.stringify.
I have checked in chrome's console and error shows to be with wherever JSON.stringify exists.

SOLUTION: Apparently an error with JSON object parsing was causing this error. This question is not a duplicate as mentioned.

Comment: You need to make your server use https if you are going to load data from a  secure protocol.

Comment: @FraserCrosbie I am using facebook and google login, and this is happening when I am not even requesting to their server or any other secure server. Just trying to make a request to localhost